# How can I keep my wubi installation after formatting Windows?

Tags: windows, backup, wubi, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can re-use Ubuntu which was installed via Wubi on Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54981/how-can-re-use-ubuntu-which-was-installed-via-wubi-on-windows-7)

Well I need to format my Windows 7 PC with a wubi installation. Is there a way I can backup the virtual hard drive files, then format my pc, install Wubi and put the hard drive files back?

Comment: I thought you wanted to migrate to a normal dual boot, not reinstall Wubi - so ignore my above comment. You can refer to this instead: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54981/how-can-re-use-ubuntu-which-was-installed-via-wubi-on-windows-7

Comment: Mate, I would be rather happy if You could move the comment as an answer, so I can vote it as a correct answer, thanks.