# Move WUBI installation of Ubuntu to a different partition in Windows

Tags: 12.04, installation, memory-usage

I don't have a lot of space on my D: drive and Ubuntu is taking 15 gigs of it so I wonder, is there a way of moving Ubuntu from D: to C: while keeping the files that exists on Ubuntu?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Make backup copy of all important data in Ubuntu into an external device. If the following does not work, you may lose all your data.**
2. Copy the `root.disk` file from `D:\Ubuntu\Disks` to a safe place.
   You may put it in your "My Documents" for the time being.
3. Uninstall Ubuntu using Control Panel.
4. Reboot.
5. Install Ubuntu in C: using WUBI. **Make sure when installing to C: that you choose the same Disk Size as the Disk you already have. This prevents errors.**
6. Replace `C:\Ubuntu\Disks\root.disk` with the root.disk you had
   copied before.
7. Reboot.

**One more step**

*See https://askubuntu.com/a/55029/14916 for details (Thanks to @bcbc for pointing out this part.) The following is taken from that answer:*

e.g. if `D:` is `/dev/sda2` and `C:` is `/dev/sda1`, then you'd hit 'e' on the first entry of the grub menu and change:

`set root=(hd0,2)` becomes `set root=(hd0,1)`

Delete the line - `search --no-floppy xxx` (as this overrides the previous set root command using the old UUID)

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxxx root=/dev/sda2 ...` becomes `linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxx root=/dev/sda1 ...`

This is a one-time override - hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot, and make sure you run `sudo update-grub` after booting to fix the grub.cfg menu so it works the next time.

PS: There may be some variations. `(hd0,2)` could be `(hd0, msdos2)` or `(/dev/sda, msdos2)` depending on the version of Grub. Also `root=/dev/sda2` may be `root=UUID=xxxxx`

Comment: Make sure when installing to C: that you choose the same Disk Size as the Disk you already have and set everything exactly as you had it set to before. Prevents errors. (ie: Same Username and Password, etc...)

Comment: But if I want to make the size of ubuntu larger, for example 30 gigs instead of 15?

Comment: @YehonatanTsirolnik That gets more complicated and is the topic of a different question. It'll involve booting from an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB, making a new Disk Image, and Transferring the Data from the Old Disk to the New. Open a new question for that.

Comment: @YehonatanTsirolnik: This increasing the virtual disk size is a separate question, answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118300/increase-size-of-root-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-in-windows . Ask a new question if needed.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much :) This helped me a lot.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: This answer is missing some important info... the partition info is used by grub to boot the wubi install (and this is contained on the root.disk). So the first time you boot, you have to tell grub about the new partition. Check the bottom of this answer for more info: http://askubuntu.com/a/55029/14916

Comment: @bcbc Thank you very much for pointing out this important step. I have taken parts of your answer to fix mine. Let me know if this makes sense.