# Transfering a WuBi installation of Ubuntu to another disk?

Tags: wubi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Wubi on C: by mistake and started installing programs and downloading code for a bachelor's thesis on it. C: is too small and causing performance issues and I would like to move the entire thing to D:.

How do I go about this without losing anything? Being quite new to Ubuntu/Linux, I'm not sure where I'd find everything my supervisor and I installed.

Comment: See this post.http://askubuntu.com/questions/225073/move-wubi-installation-of-ubuntu-to-a-different-partition-in-windows

Comment: How about you make a real install? WUBI is not maintained neither recomended.