# Move WUBI installation of Ubuntu to a different partition in Windows failed

Tags: 12.10, wubi

I tried to move my WUBI installation according to this:
[Move WUBI installation of Ubuntu to a different partition in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225073/move-wubi-installation-of-ubuntu-to-a-different-partition-in-windows).
But when I boot Ubuntu, it can't find the root.disk file. Is there any way to restore it?
I have Ubuntu 12.10. Please help.

Comment: Did you actually try to boot the new, temporary Wubi installation you created in step 5 from the question you posted? And are you sure you didn't change anything compared to the situation before? (exact filename, location, disk size, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a copy of the original root.disk in a safe place? If not restore the original file from Windows backup and keep in a safe place.

1. Uninstall Ubuntu from control panel.
2. Reboot.
3. Reinstall using WUBI using **exactly the same specifications as the
   original**.
4. Reboot to Ubuntu and check that Ubuntu boots correctly.
5. Reboot to Windows and copy the original from the safe place to the
   boot location, such as `C:\Ubuntu\Disks`.
6. Reboot to Ubuntu.

**One more step**

*See https://askubuntu.com/a/55029/14916 for details (Thanks to bcbc for pointing out this part.) The following is taken from that answer:*

Assuming Ubuntu is being moved from `D:` to `C:` and if `D:` is `/dev/sda2` and `C:` is `/dev/sda1`, then you'd hit 'e' on the first entry of the grub menu and change:

`set root=(hd0,2)` becomes `set root=(hd0,1)`

Delete the line - `search --no-floppy xxx` (as this overrides the previous set root command using the old UUID)

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxxx root=/dev/sda2 ...` becomes `linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxx root=/dev/sda1 ...`

This is a one-time override - hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot, and make sure you run `sudo update-grub` after booting to fix the grub.cfg menu so it works the next time.

PS: There may be some variations. `(hd0,2)` could be `(hd0, msdos2)` or `(/dev/sda, msdos2)` depending on the version of Grub. Also `root=/dev/sda2` may be `root=UUID=xxxxx`

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that, but my disk file seems to be damaged. :(